# Produce searchable PDF using pillow

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, python-imaging-library

I am mass producing PDFs and it would be easier to make the text searchable while I am making the images, than to run every pdf through adobe OCR. Am I able to do that in pillow? is there an easier way to make them searchable than to make all of the PDFs then convert images of text back to text

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

p_height = int(11*300)
p_width = int(8.5*300)
image = Image.new('RGB', (p_width, p_height),(255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("RobotoMono.ttf", size=50)

text ='''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam
aliquet suscipit. Aliquam a hendrerit lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum
primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;
Nullam ultricies purus a lobortis pharetra.  Nullam rutrum rutrum 
ipsum, at cursus lectus vestibulum a. Sed congue mi sed libero
venenatis, a rutrum eros vestibulum. Morbi nec lobortis erat. 
Integer nec efficitur magna. Mauris sollicitudin tortor et 
finibus varius. Curabitur dictum aliquet volutpat.'''
    
draw.text((50, p_height//2), text, (0,0,0), font)
image.save('PDF.pdf', "PDF", resolution=300)
```

How would I make the above code produce a searchable pdf without having to run it through adobe?

Comment: This doesn't make sense! You have the text already, and you want to make it into a bitmapped image that you can't search, and then OCR it to get back the text you already have. Why would you do that? Why not just make a textual PDF instead of an image PDF?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I am making pricing catalogs and they all have different information depending on which customer it is going to. It adds pictures to a layout with the relevant information. How would I make textual pdf from a csv and png files? Some of the documents get large and the customers like to be able to search for the sections they need using the find feature. I am trying to avoid doing what you described.

Comment: I would convert the CSV of text and images to **markdown** (which is very simple) and then use `pandoc` to make a textual PDF, with a command like `pandoc --base-header-level=2 --toc -f markdown -c stylesheet.css -o result.pdf` Manual here... https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html Then try `pdfgrep` to search for words in the resulting PDF.